Azure Entra Id can login to Azure SQL database server without USER or LOGIN
I have an Entra Id "admin@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft". This Entra Id:

Can create new Entra Id users;
Is the Microsoft Entra admin for an Azure SQL database server, which has a few databases;
Earlier in SSMS I connected to the database engine with that Entra Id.

Whilst logged in as "admin@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft", I have now created a new Entra Id "littlebird@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft". Just created it, nothing more. I didn't create a USER or LOGIN for that Entra Id in my database server or any databases.
I would expect that if I open SSMS and try to connect to the database engine using "littlebird@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft", it would deny me.
However, it lets me connect. The grey bar at the top of Object Explorer with the server name then shows me "admin@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft" (even though I connected with "littlebird@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft").
If I then open a new query window (right click on a database that is not master, "New Query" from context menu), the tab above the query window then shows me "littlebird@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft".
I am then able to SELECT against a table and even do an UPDATE.
I use SSMS version 19.0.2
I guess SSMS somehow remembers "admin@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft" and uses that instead of "littlebird@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft". But that is just my speculation.
How do I check whether an Entra Id has access to a database or not?

check this link and list all the principal added to your database along with permissions.


How do I check whether an Entra Id has access to a database or not?

To check the permissions granted to principal you need to use below query which lists the permissions explicitly granted or denied to database principals.

As per this MS document
SELECT pr.principal_id, pr.name, pr.type_desc,   
  pr.authentication_type_desc, pe.state_desc, pe.permission_name  
FROM sys.database_principals AS pr  
JOIN sys.database_permissions AS pe  
  ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id;


The above query will return you the output like below, if the connect permission is assigned to the user means it can connect to the database:

Sometimes, SSMS caches tokens from previous connections, and use it. You can resolve this by closing and reopening SSMS, or by disconnecting and reconnecting using the correct credentials.
Also check Review any role assignments granted at the server or database level via Azure RBAC (e.g., if littlebird@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft has been given special permissions) by going your Database >> Access control (IAM) >> Check access >> View my access > search your Entra user if it has any RBAC role assigned.

Re. clearing the SSMS cache, I tried closing and reopening SSMS, and disconnectiong and reconnecting to littlebird@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft in the Object Explorer window, to no avail. Also, littlebird@mycompanydev.onmicrosoft has no RBAC roles assigned at all.

Re. the query, thanks for that, I'll use that for now to check permissions.
